# Update association on child delete

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

I have three entity classes. 
Product, Category, and SubCategory.

A Category has a OneToMany relation with SubCategory

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "category_id")
private Long categoryId;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
private List<SubCategory> subCategories;
```

}

The product is assocciated with a Category and one of its SubCategories

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTS")
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = ("id"))
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "category", unique = false, nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
private Category category;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "sub_category", unique = false, nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
private SubCategory subCategory;

}
```

now if I delete a Category, all its SubCatogries are deleted, but I also want the associations in Product to be updated to null. I thought of manually fetching all the products with the associated deleted Category and updating them manually, but is there a way to handle this with JPA annotations?

Comment: Also, if I update a category ( let's say I removed subCategory A), then I should also update the accossiated products.

Answer (score 1):

This update from JPA will be very inefficient in performance perspective.

Your table *PRODUCTS* has columns *category* abd *sub_category* which linked with correspond tables by foreign keys. Add to end of definition of each of these columns string 'ON DELETE SET NULL' and what you want will be done by database automatically.

Comment: can I do this if I am using JPA to create the schema?

Comment: See annotation *@ForeignKey* and it's field *foreignKeyDefinition*.

Comment: I tried it on MySQL, it didn't work. What I'm I doing wrong?    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sub_category", 
     foreignKey=@ForeignKey(foreignKeyDefinition = "ON DELETE 
     SET NULL"))
 private SubCategory subCategory;`

Comment: This annotation will work only if you generate your databaae from your jpa model.

Comment: I am generating my database from the JPA modal. I recreated it after adding the new annotations

Comment: It didn't work because I was using MyISAM which does  not support foreign keys and cascading deletes/updates

Answer (score 0):

The **Product** entity has a ManyToOne relationship with **SubCategory** that means that the **SubCategory** entity has a **OneToMany** relationship with **Product**. So, in the **SubCategory** class, where you have defined the OneToMany relationship, you need to mention the cascadetype = remove

> @manytoone(cascade = cascadetype.remove)

Hope it solves your problem

Comment: Actually `SubCategory` doesn't have a relation with `Category` but thanks.